# How to retry HTTP request when response in pending

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I am making an HTTP request to the server to get a file upload status which takes a little time around 3 to 4 minutes. If the request is in the pending state or it has not returned the status of `success or error` then I want to recall the HTTP request until I get the response.
I am using a set timeout recursively, **Is there any way to achieve it using RXJS operators**

```
getImportStatus(): void {
        this.restaurantService
            .getImportStatus()
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
            .subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    if (
                        res.result.status == 'error' ||
                        res.result.status == 'success'
                    ) {
                        this.spinner.hide();
                        if (res.result.status == 'error') {
                            this.toastr.error(
                                res.result.restaurant.message,
                                'Error!'
                            );
                        } else {
                            this.toastr.success(
                                res.result.message,
                                'Success'
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                       //retry the same http request
                        //after every three seconds
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            this.getImportStatus();
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                },
                (err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
    }
```

Comment: Hint: The overload of `subscribe` that takes two functions is deprecated and shouldn't be used in newer versions of RxJS. Instead pass an object: `.subscribe({ next: (res) => ..., error: (e) => ....})`

Comment: I'd assume you are uploading the file from within the same application? In this case it would be better and easier to use the ``observe: 'events'`` option within the upload HTTP request. This way you can get the final HTTP status code and calculate and display the upload progress to the user.